# Issue loading signed .Net dll in Excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, dll

I work in a company and I have to call a VB.Net-dll from Excel using VBA.
It works fine when the dll is **not** signed, which I build with Visual Studio 2019.
But when the same dll is signed with a key, it does not work.

I get the error bellow, which says *that the file or assembly, or a dependdency of it could not be found. Unknown error.*

```
Die Datei oder Assembly "Company.Tools.ExcelXmlCreator, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c4fc2c77b10477c5" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Unbekannter Fehler (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))
-2147467259
```

VBA Code: it crashes at *"Set exl = domain.CreateInstanceFrom(..."*

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim clr As mscoree.CorRuntimeHost
    Dim domain As mscorlib.AppDomain
    Dim exl As Object
    Set clr = New mscoree.CorRuntimeHost

    clr.Start
    clr.GetDefaultDomain domain
     
    On Error GOto err_handler

    Set exl = domain.CreateInstanceFrom("C:\Users\Desktop\Company.Tools.ExcelXmlCreator.dll", "Company.Tools.ExcelXmlCreator.ExcelXml").Unwrap

    Dim folderPath  As String
    Dim folderPathExists As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim k As Boolean

    folderPath = Cells(1, 2).Value
    folderPathExists = Dir(folderPath, vbDirectory)

    If folderPathExists <> "" Then
        k = exl.Execute(wb, folderPath)
        MsgBox (exl.Message2)
    Else
        MsgBox (folderPath + "does not exist")
    End If

    Set exl = Nothing

    clr.Stop

    Exit Sub

err_handler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Debug.Print Err.Number
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm taking a bit of a guess but I think it's a register conflict.  Do the signed and unsigned versions use the same name?  Did you unregister the unsigned one before registering the signed version?

Comment: Are you also signing your VBA project?

Comment: @AutomateThis - Yes, at first I was working with a non-signed dll.. but then the department manager told me we have to use a signed dll.. yes, I used cominterop, but we thought that maybe our customers do not have admin rights, so we removed it and so on. I used regasm. I changed namespaces.. a lot of things..

Comment: @HackSlash emmm No, should I? Is it possible? I didnt know that.

Comment: Yup: https://www.digicert.com/kb/code-signing/microsoft-office-vba.htm

Comment: @HackSlash I will try it tomorrow at work and I will answer you back.. thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Does the signed assembly only reference other signed assemblies?  [A strong-named assembly can only use types from other strong-named assemblies.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/create-use-strong-named).